# Get rid of TabNine in Jupyter Lab and get back the native (tab activated) autocomplete on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: autocomplete, uninstallation, jupyter-lab, tabnine

I was trying to get rid of tabnine and get back the normal (tab activated) autocomplete in Jupyter Lab.
Firstly I uninstalled TabNine with:
 `jupyter labextension uninstall tabnine`
TabNine was gone but launching a new session of jupyter lab in the terminal every few second the following warning appeared:
`[W 2022-06-30 11:51:28.051 ServerApp] 404 POST /tabnine?1656582688048 (127.0.0.1) 1.78ms referer=http://localhost:8889/lab`
and more importantly the native autocomplete was not working.
I force a clean reinstall of jupyter lab but did not change anything.
In the end I just looked for all the files names tabnine and eliminate them (not a very safe approach in general) and it work!
The two files causing the problem were:
.local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config/jupyterlab_tabnine.json
.local/etc/jupyter/jupyter_server_config/jupyterlab_tabnine.json

I wanted just to leave this here and find out if there would have been a faster and safer solution to get rid of TabNine.

Comment: What is the result of `jupyter labextension list` for you?

Comment: @krassowski, I cannot reproduce it at this point because I clean reinstall jupyter lab and all the extensions.